# How to manage SQLite database via (S)FTP?

Tags: database, sqlite, ftp

I'm looking for a tool to manage a SQLite database. There is the Firefox Plugin out there, but I would need to open and view the contents of a SQLite database via FTP (or better SFTP/SCP). Currently I would have to copy the database everytime there is a change in the database. Are there are better ways for doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a virtual disk via SFTP (eg. using our *free* SFTP Net Drive tool) and then manage the remotely located DB file using any SQLite tool which accesses database files.

Comment: I also thought about synchronizing via FTP (with tools like TotalCommander, TB-FtpSync, ...), but yours seems to work!